# Replace number format in Word

Tags: excel, vba, replace, ms-word, number-formatting

I am using a excel vba code to paste some variable data to word document (using replace all function). But I cannot paste it in correct format.

I have a word document template and get some parametric value from excel and replace it with a spesific text in word document.

```
Set myRange = docWord.Content
myRange.Find.Execute FindText:="TEXT_TEMPLATE", ReplaceWith:=amountvariable, Replace:=wdReplaceAll, MatchCase:=True
```

For example; in excel file:
amountvariable = Range("A1")

My Word Document has a sentence: "The amount is TEXT_TEMPLATE."

The code takes the value A1 cell and replace the phrase "TEXT_TEMPLATE" with "amountvariable".

However the format of the number is like 10000. I want to see it as 10.000,00. How can I make it with the right number format.

Answer (score 0):

Just format the string variable according your version of "right" ;-)

```
Option Explicit
Sub format10k()

Dim dbl10k As Double
Dim str10k As String

    dbl10k = 10000#
    str10k = Format(dbl10k, "#,##0.00")
    
    Debug.Print str10k
    
End Sub
```